# Finding the residue at point $z=0$ and $z=\infty$ of $f(z)=\frac{z^ne^{\frac{1}{z}}}{1+z} $

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

Let the residue of the function $f(z)=\frac{z^ne^{\frac{1}{z}}}{1+z} $ at the points $z=0$ and $z=\infty$ be $A$ and $B$ respectively. Show that if $n$ is a non-negative integer, then 
$$A=(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{e}+\frac{1}{n!}-\frac{1}{(n-1)!}+\ldots+(-1)^{n}\frac{1}{1!};$$

$$A+B+(-1)^n\frac{1}{e}=0$$

To find the residue at point $z=0$, I think I need to write the Laurent series around point $z=0$.
$$f(z)=z^n(\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(-z)^m)(\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{-j}}{j!}).$$
To find the resduie at point $z=0$, I guess it's enough to count the coeffiecnt of $z^{-1}.$

However, I don't know how to look at this sum to get the desired $A$. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we expand $e^{1/z}$ and $\frac1{1+z}$ in Laurent and Taylor series to write

$$\frac{e^{1/z}}{1+z}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty  \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{j!} z^{m-j}$$

Next, letting $k=m-j$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{m=0}^\infty  \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{j!} z^{m-j}&=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \sum_{k=-\infty}^m \frac{(-1)^mz^k}{(m-k)!}\\\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \sum_{k=-\infty}^{-1} \frac{(-1)^mz^k}{(m-k)!}+\sum_{m=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^m \frac{(-1)^mz^k}{(m-k)!}\\\\
\end{align}$$

Finally, the residue of $z^n \frac{e^{1/z}}{1+z}$ at $z=0$ is, therefore, simply the coefficient on the $z^{-1}$ term.  This is given by

$$\begin{align}
\text{Res}\left(z^n \frac{e^{1/z}}{1+z},z=0\right)&=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{(m+n+1)!}\\\\
&=\sum_{m=n+1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{m-n-1}}{m!} \\\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{m-n-1}}{m!}-\sum_{m=0}^n \frac{(-1)^{m-n-1}}{m!} \\\\
&=(-1)^{n+1}\left(e^{-1}-\sum_{m=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^m}{m!}\right)
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!